# Apache SSI includes and node

Tags: node.js, apache, ssi

I have apache running and it is configured to serve some SSI includes, it all works fine if the application is deployed through Apache, however I would like to deploy a node test server and at the same time Apache to understand the SSI includes. Is that even possible?

I have a work around by loading the SSI includes as an JSON object on the front end but would like the SSI includes to be processed at the server level.

Comment: I had mixed results with https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssi

Comment: I saw that plugin but didnt understand it. Does that package converts Apache includes and obeys those rules? Or would I have to replicate what happens in Apache but in node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using node-request

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred 
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received 
  console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage. 
});
```